# Getting TabLayout view in fragment returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I am trying to add a `TabLayout` into a fragment, I went over the topic of implementing a `TabLayout` through multiple tutorials and they were roughly the same. I followed the tutorials and changed a few methods to suit a fragment rather than the usual activity but after compiling it returns an error with getting the `Tablayout` from the xml file through `findViewById`. As much as I have checked, then I haven't managed to find what is done wrong. The `TabLayout` is in a fragment because I am using `BottomNavigation` for the application's main navigation but i would like to use a `TabLayout` for displaying extra info inside the fragment.

Here is the Fragment that holds the TabLayout

```
public class LocationsFragment extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //The next line has the NullPointerException.
        TabLayout tabLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        TabItem discoveredTab = getView().findViewById(R.id.discoveredTab);
        TabItem allLocationsTab = getView().findViewById(R.id.allTab);
        ViewPager viewPager = getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getPosition() == 0){
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
                        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
        return root;
    }
```

Here is the PagerAdapter class

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private int numOfTabs;


    public  PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, int numOfTabs){
        super(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new TabDiscoveredFragment();
            case 1:
                return new TabAllFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

And here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.journey.JourneyFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/statLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_round_all">

//TextViews which are irrelevant to the example        

    </RelativeLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/statLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/discoveredTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Discovered" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/allTab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="All locations" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `getView()` in `onCreateView()` fragment lifecycle method.. because the fragment view is not yet created; actually `onCreateView()` creates this view and returns it back.

You can only use `getView()` in fragment lifecycle methods that are after `onCreateView()`

To solve this you need to use the inflated view itself, to apply that on your code, replace `getView()` with `root`... but declare it at the very beginning of the method.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
    
    //The next line has the NullPointerException.
    TabLayout tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabItem discoveredTab = root.findViewById(R.id.discoveredTab);
    TabItem allLocationsTab = root.findViewById(R.id.allTab);
    ViewPager viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    return root;
}
```

Comment: If I may, then I would ask one more question. Now with your help the Tabs work but the content from the tabs is positioned to the start of the parent but it would have to be contained below the TabLayout in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: @EdwardAarma excuse me I couldn't get you.. can you show some photo

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation, now I added a screenshot to the end of the question. There you can see that the TabLayout is in the middle of the screen, the tab should start below it but you can see that in the top left corner is the contents of the tab (the word "discovered").

Comment: you need to make the ViewPager to be below the tab layout by adding `android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"` to the ViewPager